# How to create a chart in Google Sheets for yearly value growth when the data is separated by quarters?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

How to create a chart in Google Sheets for yearly value growth when the data is separated by quarters?

For
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Year name**
`=mid(OFFSET(A$1,4*ROWS(A$1:A1)-4,,1),4,4)`

**Value**
`=SUM(OFFSET(B$1,4*ROWS(B$1:B1)-4,,4))`

Enter these formula in cell D1 and E1 and copy down for as many years data exists.

**Logic**
Both formula rely on the `OFFSET` and `ROWS` functions.

- `OFFSET` returns a range reference
- `ROWS` returns the number of rows in an range.

The Year value looks at Column A; it returns a single cell, every 4th entry, and `MID` extracts the year name.
The Annual value looks at Column B; it returns a range of four cells, and adds those values.

Credit: [myonlinetraininghub.com](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-formulas-to-summarise-monthly-data-into-quarters)